# Returning a long long value

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, long-long

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    long long x = test();
    printf("%lld\n", x);

    return 1;
}

long long test()
{   
    return 1111111111111111111;
}
```

The output is 734294471 . If I replace the call to `test()` by a the number, the output is as I expect. I checked the value of x using a debugger and it wasn't set the to value returned by the function. What is going wrong?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with the Visual C++ compiler.

Comment: Your IDE is not relevant for this sort of question, and `<stdio.h>` is not a C++ header - if for some reason you needed to use the C-style IO library in C++ code, `#include <cstdio>` instead.

Comment: @Karl I mention the IDE as it might affect the compiler settings.

Comment: Excellent question, which pinpoints briefly and clearly exactly the problem I had. I'm surprised it didn't get more upvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare `test` before you call it, otherwise C assumes it returns `int`.

Comment: Isn't this behaviour deprecated even in C nowadays? I would have expected a compilation error, actually. At least in C++ this -- using a function without having seen a declaration before -- is illegal.

Comment: this solved it! Enabling all compiler warnings showed the warning.

Comment: @tobyodavies: It is allowed in C89, which is the latest C standard that the Microsoft compiler supports.  Presumably the OP is compiling this code as C, rather than C++.

Comment: @Pulkit, you posted on SO _before_ reading the warnings from your compiler... seriously?

Comment: @tobydavies I haven't worked with VC++ compiler a lot and didn't know that some warnings are disabled by default. The original compilation didn't show any warnings.

Answer (score 4):

IIRC, a long long constant in C/C++ is suffixed by 'LL'.

```
long long test() {
    return 1111111111111111111LL;
}
```

Your compiler is treating your constant as a 32-bit long (if you take your constant modulo 2^32, you get 734294471.)

Comment: I thought one L made it a `long` and a second made it a `long long`

Comment: The type of an unsuffixed decimal constant is the first out of `int`, `long int` and `long long int` that can represent the number.  The `LL` suffix is only required to force a *smaller* number that would otherwise be of type `int` or `long` to be of type `long long` instead.

Comment: the suffix is not necessary because if a constant doesn't fit in `int` it'll have type `long` or `long long` depending on its value http://stackoverflow.com/q/8108642/995714

Answer (score 1):

Try adding LL to your return value:

```
long long test()
{   
    return 1111111111111111111LL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the suffix LL to your literal and see what happens. Presumably the compiler conberts the literal to an int. Are you getting any warnings from the compiler?

Comment: Don't presume, *know*.  For a decimal integer constant without a suffix, the compiler picks the first out of `int`, `long` and `long long` that is long enough to represent the number.