# Bitwise shift operation in C on uint64_t variable

Tags: c, 64-bit, bit-manipulation

I have the following sample code:

```
uint64_t x, y;
x = ~(0xF<<24);
y = ~(0xFF<<24);
```

The result would be:

```
x=0xfffffffff0ffffff
y=0xfffff
```

Can anyone explain the difference? Why x is calculated over 64 bit and y only on 32?

Comment: [Type of integer literals not int by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8108642/995714), [What is the default type of integral literals represented in hex or octal in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38782709/995714)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default operation is 32 bit.

```
x=~(0xf<<24);
```

This code could be disassembled into the following steps:

```
int32_t a;
a=0x0000000f;
a<<=24;   // a=0x0f000000;
a=~a;     // a=0xf0ffffff;
x=(uint64_t)a;  // x = 0xfffffffff0ffffff;
```

And,

```
y = ~(0xFF<<24);

int32_t a;
a=0x000000ff;
a<<=24;   // a=0xff000000;
a=~a;     // a=0x00ffffff;
x=(uint64_t)a;  // x = 0x000000000ffffff;
```

Comment: To be picky, the default is (signed) `int`, whatever that might be.

Comment: And strictly speaking, 0xFF<<24 for a 32-bit system is undefined behavior and the result could be anything.

Comment: I cannot agree. The behavior should be predictable. If 'a' has type 'char', then 0xff<<24 will result a negative value; otherwise, if 'a' has type short or int, it will be a positive value.

Answer (score 2):

Because `0x0f << 24` is a positive number when viewed as an `int`, it's sign-extended to a positive number, i.e. to `0x00000000_0f000000` (the underscore is just for readability, C does not support this syntax). This is then inverted into what you're seeing.

`0xff << 24` on the other hand is negative, so it's sign-extended differently.

Comment: Strictly speaking, 0xFF<<24 for a 32-bit system is undefined behavior and the result could be anything.

Answer (score 2):

Other posters have shown why it does this. But to get the expected results:

```
uint64_t x, y; 
x = ~(0xFULL<<24); 
y = ~(0xFFULL<<24);
```

Or you can do this (I don't know if this is is any slower than the above though):

```
uint64_t x, y; 
x = ~(uint64_t(0xF)<<24); 
y = ~(uint64_t(0xFF)<<24);
```

Then:

```
x = 0xfffffffff0ffffff
y = 0xffffffff00ffffff
```

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behavior in your program so anything might happen.

- The integer literals 0xF or 0xFF are of type `int`, which is equivalent to `signed int`. On this particular platform, `int` is apparently 32 bits.
- The integer literal 24 is also a (signed) `int`.
- When the compiler evaluates the << operation, both operands are (signed) `int` so no implicit type promotions take place. The result of the << operation is therefore also a (signed) `int`.
- The value 0xF<<24 = 0x0F000000 fits in a (signed) `int` as a non-negative value, so everything is ok.
- The value 0xFF<<24 = 0xFF000000 *does not fit* in (signed) `int`! Here, undefined behavior is invoked and anything might happen.

ISO 9899:2011 6.5.7/4:

> "The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
>   bits are filled with zeros." /--/
>
> **"If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the result type,
>   then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

So the expression 0xFF<<24 can't be used. The program is free to print any garbage value after that.

But if we ignore that one and focus on 0x0F<24:

- 0x0F000000 is still a (signed) `int`. The ~operator is applied to this.
- The result is 0xF0FFFFFF, which is still a signed int. And on almost any system, this 32-bit hex equals a negative number in two's complement.
- This signed int is converted to the type uint64_t during assignment. This is done in two steps, first by converting it to a signed 64 bit, then by converting that signed 64 to an unsigned 64.

---

Bugs like this is why the coding standard MISRA-C contains a number of rules to ban sloppy use of integer literals in expression like this. MISRA-C compliant code must use the `u` suffix after each integer literal (MISRA-C:2004 10.6) and the code is not allowed to perform bitwise operations on signed integers (MISRA-C:2004 12.7).