# Why do the upper 32 bits of a uint64_t become one whilst performing a specific bitwise operation?

Tags: c, literals, signed, integer-promotion, uint64

Can someone please explain to me why the upper 32 bits of a `uint64_t` are set to one in case number #2:

```
uint64_t ret = 0;
ret = (((uint64_t)0x00000000000000FF) << 24);
printf("#1 [%016llX]\n", ret);

ret = (0x00000000000000FF << 24);
printf("#2 [%016llX]\n", ret);

uint32_t ret2 = 0;
ret2 = (((uint32_t)0x000000FF) << 8);
printf("#3 [%08X]\n", ret2);

ret2 = (0x000000FF << 8);
printf("#4 [%08X]\n", ret2);
```

### Output:

```
#1 [00000000FF000000]
#2 [FFFFFFFFFF000000]
#3 [0000FF00]
#4 [0000FF00]
```

https://ideone.com/xKUaTe

You'll notice I've given an "equivalent" 32bit version (cases #3 and #4) which doesn't show the same behaviour...

Comment: I heard once, somewhere, that casting int64's causes misbehavior in a small percentage of 32 bit scenarios. Unity is (or was?) known for this, this is the reason that Kerbal Space Program can't use more than 3.5Gb of RAM.
It is also the reason i quit KSP.

Comment: Suffix your numeric constants with u or ul or ull: `0xffull` (constants have a type too, numeric constants have the type *signed* int by default, unless a decimal point is present, etc)

Comment: @x13 it's unrelated here. The OP just didn't know about C's rule about promotion and type of integer literals. There's no hardware of compiler bug in the above code

Comment: It is incorrect to use `llX` for printing `uint64_t`, you must use the *macro* `PRIX64`. Likewise for `uint32_t`

Answer (score 3):

By default integer literals without a suffix will have type `int` if they fit in an `int`.

> ## [The type of the integer constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant)
>
> The type of the integer constant is the first type in which the value can fit, from the list of types which depends on which numeric base and which `integer-suffix` was used.
>
> - no suffix
> - decimal bases:
>
>   - int
>   - long int
>   - unsigned long int (until C99)
>   - long long int (since C99)
> - binary, octal, or hexadecimal bases:
>
>   - int
>   - unsigned int
>   - long int
>   - unsigned long int
>   - long long int (since C99)
>   - unsigned long long int (since C99)
> - ...

As a result `0x00000000000000FF` will be an `int` regardless of how many zeros you put in. You can check that by printing `sizeof 0x00000000000000FF`

Therefore, `0x00000000000000FF << 24` results in 0xFF000000 which is a negative value<sup>1</sup>. That'll again be sign extended when casting to `uint64_t`, filling the top 32 bits with ones

Casting help, as you can see in `(uint64_t)0x00000000000000FF) << 24`, because now the shift operates on the `uint64_t` value instead of `int`. You can also use a suffix

```
0x00000000000000FFU << 24
0x00000000000000FFULL << 24
```

The first line above does the shift in `unsigned int` and then do zero extension to cast to `uint64_t`. The second one does the operation in `unsigned long long` directly

`0x000000FF << 8` doesn't expose the same behavior because the result is 0xFF00 which doesn't have the sign bit set, but it will if you do `(int16_t)0x000000FF << 8`

There are a lot of related and duplicate questions:

- [Type of integer literals not int by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8108642/995714)
- [What Are Integer Literal Type? And How They Are Stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41405578/995714)
- [what is the reason for explicitly declaring L or UL for long values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13134956/995714)
- ...

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically shifting into the sign bit results in undefined behavior but in your case the compiler has chosen to leave the result the same as when you shift an unsigned value: `0xFFU << 24 = 0xFF000000U` which when converted to signed produces a negative value

See

- [Bitwise shift operation in C on uint64_t variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9290823/995714)
- [Why does shifting 0xff left by 24 bits result in an incorrect value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46246411/995714)

Comment: `0xFF << 24` results in *undefined behavior*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I knew that but I wanted to keep it short. I've added the note now