# Weird result after assigning 2^31 to a signed and unsigned 32-bit integer variable

Tags: c++, bit-shift, unsigned-integer

As the question title reads, assigning 2^31 to a signed and unsigned 32-bit integer variable gives an unexpected result.

Here is the short program (in `C++`), which I made to see what's going on:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long n = 1<<31;
    long long n2 = 1<<31;  // this works as expected
    printf("%llu\n",n);
    printf("%lld\n",n2);
    printf("size of ULL: %d, size of LL: %d\n", sizeof(unsigned long long), sizeof(long long) );
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
MyPC / # c++ test.cpp -o test
MyPC / # ./test
18446744071562067968      <- Should be 2^31 right?
-2147483648               <- This is correct ( -2^31 because of the sign bit)
size of ULL: 8, size of LL: 8
```

I then added another function `p()`, to it:

```
void p()
{
  unsigned long long n = 1<<32;  // since n is 8 bytes, this should be legal for any integer from 32 to 63
  printf("%llu\n",n);
}
```

On compiling and running, this is what confused me even more:

```
MyPC / # c++ test.cpp -o test
test.cpp: In function ‘void p()’:
test.cpp:6:28: warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
MyPC / # ./test 
0
MyPC /
```

Why should the compiler complain about left shift count being too large? `sizeof(unsigned long long`) returns 8, so doesn't that mean 2^63-1 is the max value for that data type?

It struck me that maybe n*2 and n<<1, don't always behave in the same manner, so I tried this:

```
void s()
{
   unsigned long long n = 1;
   for(int a=0;a<63;a++) n = n*2;
   printf("%llu\n",n);
}
```

This gives the correct value of 2^63 as the output which is `9223372036854775808` (I verified it using python). But what is wrong with doing a left shit?

> A left arithmetic shift by n is equivalent to multiplying by 2<sup>n</sup>
>   (provided the value does not overflow)

**-- Wikipedia**

The value is not overflowing, only a minus sign will appear since the value is 2^63 (all bits are set).

I'm still unable to figure out what's going on with left shift, can anyone please explain this?

PS: This program was run on a 32-bit system running linux mint (if that helps)

Comment: This should be `unsigned long long n = 1ULL<<31;`

Comment: god! was it this easy?! Why didn't I think of it. anyways, yes 1ULL<<31 does work. so thanks!

Comment: [Type of integer literals not int by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8108642/995714), [What is the default type of integral literals represented in hex or octal in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38782709/995714), [Is unsigned long int correct for this operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35119136/995714), [bit shifting with unsigned long type produces wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31744305/995714)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On this line:

```
unsigned long long n = 1<<32;
```

The problem is that the literal `1` is of type `int` - which is probably only 32 bits. Therefore the shift will push it out of bounds.

Just because you're storing into a larger datatype doesn't mean that everything in the expression is done at that larger size.

So to correct it, you need to either cast it up or make it an `unsigned long long` literal:

```
unsigned long long n = (unsigned long long)1 << 32;
unsigned long long n = 1ULL << 32;
```

Comment: With regards to the last suggestion: **please** use caps for the type designators.  With many fonts, distinguishing between `1ll` and `111` can be difficult, if not impossible; `1LL` is clear and unambiguous (and there is not suffix `O` to create problems with `0`).

Answer (score 5):

The reason `1 << 32` fails is because `1` doesn't have the right type (it is `int`). The compiler doesn't do any converting magic before the assignment itself actually happens, so `1 << 32` gets evaluated  using `int` arithmic, giving a warning about an overflow.

Try using `1LL` or `1ULL` instead which respectively have the `long long` and `unsigned long long` type.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
unsigned long long n = 1<<32;
```

results in an overflow, because the literal 1 is of type `int`, so `1 << 32` is also an int, which is 32 bits in most cases.

The line

```
unsigned long long n = 1<<31;
```

also overflows, for the same reason. Note that 1 is of type `signed int`, so it really only has 31 bits for the value and 1 bit for the sign. So when you shift `1 << 31`, it overflows the value bits, resulting in `-2147483648`, which is then converted to an unsigned long long, which is `18446744071562067968`. You can verify this in the debugger, if you inspect the variables and convert them.

So use

```
unsigned long long n = 1ULL << 31;
```