# Printing a long in binary 64-bit representation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to print the binary representation of a long in order to practice bit manipulation and setting various bits in the long for a project I am working on. I successfully can print the bits on ints but whenever I try to print 64 bits of a long the output is screwy. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void printbits(unsigned long n){
    unsigned long i; 
    i = 1<<(sizeof(n)*4-1);
    while(i>0){
         if(n&1)
              printf("1"); 
         else 
              printf("0"); 
         i >>= 1; 
}

int main(){
    unsigned long n=10; 
    printbits(n); 
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

My output is 0000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111110.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Note that long is not necessarily 64 bits.

Comment: you need `1UL << (sizeof(n)*8-1)` [bit shifting with unsigned long type produces wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31744305/995714)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is unsigned long int correct for this operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119136/is-unsigned-long-int-correct-for-this-operation)

Comment: What output should occur with `printbits(0)`?

Answer (score 4):

- 4 isn’t the right number of bits in a byte
- Even though you’re assigning it to an `unsigned long`, `1 << …` is an `int`, so you need `1UL`
- `n&1` should be `n&i`
- There’s a missing closing brace

Fixes only:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

void printbits(unsigned long n){
    unsigned long i; 
    i = 1UL<<(sizeof(n)*CHAR_BIT-1);
    while(i>0){
         if(n&i)
              printf("1"); 
         else 
              printf("0"); 
         i >>= 1;
    }
}

int main(){
    unsigned long n=10; 
    printbits(n); 
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

And if you want to print a 64-bit number specifically, I would hard-code 64 and use `uint_least64_t`.

Comment: Ry-, for fun, to cope with those padded `unsigned long` implementations, (rotting in a computer graveyard), code could use the portable `i = ULONG_MAX - ULONG_MAX/2;`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `i = 1<<(sizeof(n)*4-1)` is not correct for a number of reasons.

1. `sizeof(n)*4` is 32, not 64.  you probably want `sizeof(n)*8`
2. `1<<63` may give you overflow because 1 may be 32-bits by default.  You should use `1ULL<<(sizeof(n)*8-1)`
3. `unsigned long` is not necessarily 64 bits.  You should use `unsigned long long`

If you want to be extra thorough, use `sizeof(n) * CHAR_BIT` (defined in `<limits.h>`).

In general, you should use `stdint` defines (e.g. `uint64_t`) whenever possible.

Comment: You want `sizeof(n) * CHAR_BIT` (defined in `<limits.h>`). And if you want a type that's exactly 64 bits, use `uint64_t`. If you want at least 64 bits, use `unsigned long long` or `uint_least64_t`.

Comment: `1ULL` would be better (`1LL << 63` is undefined behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printbits(unsigned long number, unsigned int num_bits_to_print)
{
    if (number || num_bits_to_print > 0) {
        printbits(number >> 1, num_bits_to_print - 1);
        printf("%d", number & 1);
    }
}
```

We keep calling the function recursively until either we've printed enough bits, or we've printed the whole number, whichever takes more bits.

wrapping this in another function directly does exactly what you want:

```
void printbits64(unsigned long number) {
    printbits(number, 64);
}
```

Comment: There is no recursive call.

Comment: Oops, my bad, I renamed the function to be more inline with the name OP chose and forgot to rename the recursive call too. Should be fixed now.