# C++ how do i keep compiler from making implicit conversions when calling functions?

Tags: c++, casting, default, implicit, explicit

Here's the deal:

When i have a function with default arguments like this one

```
int foo (int a, int*b, bool c = true);
```

If i call it by mistake like this:

```
foo (1, false);
```

The compiler will convert false to an int pointer and call the function with b pointing to 0.

I've seen people suggest the template approach to prevent implicit type conversion:

```
template <class T>
int foo<int> (int a, T* b, bool c = true);
```

But that approach is too messy and makes the code confusing.

There is the explicit keyword but it only works for constructors.

What i would like is a clean method for doing that similarly to the explicit method so that when i declare the method like this:

```
(keyword that locks in the types of parameters) int foo (int a, int*b, bool c = true);
```

and call it like this:

```
foo (1, false);
```

the compiler would give me this:

```
foo (1, false);
         ^
ERROR: Wrong type in function call (expected int* but got bool)
```

Is there such a method?

Comment: What do you expect it to do when you have `void foo(short a, int b, long c)` and you call it like `foo(1, 1, 1)` ? "Oh those implicit conversions are okay"

Comment: Actually those aren't conversions because integers are ambiguous data. I want to prevent mostly conversion when calling foo (a (int), b (some other object) ); Those typos have given me a lot of headaches.

Comment: `1` is an `int`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8108658/242520

Comment: The problem you're having is unrelated to implicit conversions; it's about literals. The compiler *already* gives the error you expect in the case of implicit conversions, such as `bool x = false; foo(1, x);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such method. Template is good for such thing, I think. However, in gcc for example there is flag `-Wconversion-null`, and for code with `foo(1, false)` it will give warning

> converting «false» to pointer type for argument 2 of «int foo(int,
>   int*, bool)» [-Wconversion-null]

and in clang there is a flag `-Wbool-conversion`

> initialization of pointer of type 'int *' to null from a constant
>   boolean expression [-Wbool-conversion]

Comment: With gcc you could pair that with `-Werror` and maybe `-Werror=` and get warning(s) as errors! Exactly what OP wanted!

Comment: That's a shame. I hope they add this feature someday so i can stop using the int foo (int a, int b) { foo (a, b, true); } =(

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to set the warning level properly, and not ignore warnings.

For example gcc, has the `-Wall` option, which handles lots of problematic cases, and will show next warning in your case (g++ 4.8.1):

```
garbage.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
garbage.cpp:13:13: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type for argument 2 of ‘int foo(int, int*, bool)’ [-Wconversion-null]
  foo(0,false);
```