# How (~(0)) will be interpreted in c?

Tags: c

Recently in CCS standard library i have seen something like this

function is taking unsigned int argument.

```
delay(unsigned int)
```

This was used like this way

```
delay(~(0));
```

Now how the (~(0)) will be interpreted ?

if i used like this way

```
printf("%d",(~(0)));
```

How its treated signed int? unsigned int? long int? or unsigned char?

How its depended on system? What c spec says for this?

Comment: In `printf`, it all depends on format specifier. However you must be careful that illegal conversions are undefined (e.g: integer to float, vice-versa)

Comment: In `printf()`, it doesn't matter what the paramter ist, it doesn't even matter what the format specifier is, since parameters of variadic functions are subject to integer promotion. `printf("%d",(char)(~(0)))`, `printf("%d", (short)(~(0)))`, `printf("%d", (int)(~(0)))` will all print the same type, an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that `~` is the bitwise NOT operator, and that `0` is an integer, `sizeof(int)` bytes in size.

Since `0` is all bits set to zero, `(~0)` is all bits set to 1.

If (like most systems), your `sizeof(int)==4`, then `(~0) == 0xFFFFFFFF`.

Basically, this is `delay`ing for the maximum value possible (assuming `delay(unsigned int)`)

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("sizeof(0)=%d sizeof(~0)=%d\n", sizeof(0), sizeof(~0));
    printf("0x%X\n", (~0));
    printf("%d\n", (~0)==UINT_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
sizeof(0)=4 sizeof(~0)=4
0xFFFFFFFF
1
```

Comment: you said "0 is an integer" how u can say that? any standard?

Comment: Sure, someone could dig up the spec... but I mean, come on. *It is an integer* - what else could it be?

Comment: i doubt that  integer literal should be as smallest type as that can represent that value. Think if i use literal value more then int max value then it would be treated as int? or something else?

Comment: See [Type of integer literal not int by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8108642/119527)

Comment: Agreed now..Thanks!! We are So users we understand "spec" not "come on...blha blah.."  :)

Comment: Maybe noteworthy, that `(~0)` has type `int` and passing it to a function accepting `unsigned int`, the value will be converted, which changes the value if signed values aren't represented as a two's complement (if I'm not horribly mistaken atm). `(~0u)` would be correct in this case.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all integer constants are treated as `signed int`. However when you print it using `printf`, then the argument will be typecasted/promoted according to the format specifier.

In `delay(~(0));` I assume `delay()` will always expect a `unsigned int` argument hence `~0 == 0xffffffff` (since `int` is 4 bytes, hence `0xffffffff`) will be type promoted to `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

`~0` is an int with all 1 bits (since the unary `~` is the bitwise not operator). On most machines, it is `-1` on [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) machines like [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86)

So `printf("%d\n", ~0);` outputs -1.