# declaring floating and long types correctly in java?

Tags: java, floating-point, double

So I understand the point that if I am declaring a long variable I need to add a L in the end of number.

```
long x = 123L;
```

Same with float type also, I need to add a F at the end of variable.

```
float x = 1.1F;
```

but I was wondering why its done differently in these two cases?
I mean If i am declaring a int or any other data-type its done simply

```
int x = 1;
```

why declaration of these two data-types is done in a certain (for long and float types). I know its done this way I just want to understand why this is done in this way?

Comment: A whole number is assumed to be an `int` and a decimal is assumed to be a `double` if you want a different type you need to add an `L` or `F` or use a cast. "why this is done in this way?" how would you do it differently.  Perhaps they considered this to be the simplest way to do it.

Comment: It's simply a matter of convenience that the defaults of int and double were chosen, since they're most common.

Comment: There is actually no need for the "L" on `123L`. Without the "L" it would be an `int` literal with value 123. The conversion to long is a widening primitive conversion, and is exact. You do need "L" or "l" to declare a `long` literal that is too big for `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in **literal values**. According to [Primitive values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), literal numeric values belong for `int` and `double` types.

From [Java Language Specification. Chapter 3. Lexical Structure. 3.10 Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10):

> An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `L` or `l` (ell); otherwise it is of type `int` ([§4.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1))
>
> (...)
>
> A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is `double` and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter `D` or `d` ([§4.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)).

Comment: +1. Small edit to bold **literal**. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Rudi thanks, I've edited to bold the two words along with other changes.

Answer (score 0):

In the examples you mention the suffixes seem redundant, but there are other cases such as with two overloaded methods `test(long x)` and `test(int x)`. Whether or not a literal argument uses suffix `L` will determine which one gets called, e.g. `test(123L)` will call the first, whereas `test(123)` will call the second. And you don't want cluttered code with unnecessary suffixes, so there is no suffix `I` (nor `D`), and `123` will do just fine for a literal of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about type safety, in this way you have the control over the constants. Since int can contain less information than long it would be improper to write something like this:

`int variable = 1000000000000;`

It is allowed in C/C++ language, but the value is shinked anyway. Since Java cares about all of mistakes you need to specify L at the end of the number constant and that way you would have type mismatch error and you need to correct either value or variable type.

Comment: In C/C++ the type of decimal is "the first of the corresponding list in Table 6 in which its value can be represented.:" so it'll take int, long int or long long int depending on its value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108642/type-of-integer-literals-not-int-by-default http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Answer (score 0):

For integer literals (int, long), the default is int.

However, for floating point literals (float, double) the default is double. This is because using double potentially allows safer arithmetic on the stored values.

That is why while declaring a float or a long, you need to specifically specify them at the time of declaration using `L` or `F`.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple and Clear

Think like this, In an application I have declared **int a = 10;**, but in future, my application needed to store value something like **a = 987,654,321,321,321** then this is not possible. Compiler will throw a error message

**Example**

```
public class Z {
  public static void main(String[] args){
     int a=10;
     a=987654321321321;
     System.out.println(a);

  }
}
```

Compilation

```
    G:\Java>javac Z.java
          Z.java:4: error: integer number too large: 987654321321321
           a=987654321321321;
           ^
          1 error
```

To over come above problem, we while declaring the variable, clearly tell the compiler that the value we are going to store is of long type and not int ( So, compiler will not hava any confusion in resolving the problem)

```
      public class Z {
         public static void main(String[] args){
            long a=10L;
            a=987654321321321L;
            System.out.println(a);

          }
        }
```

Compiling and Executing The Above Code

```
   G:\Java>javac Z.java

   G:\Java>java Z
      987654321321321
```

**int:**

Int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer.

Minimum value is - 2,147,483,648.(-2^31)

Maximum value is 2,147,483,647(inclusive).(2^31 -1)

Int is generally used as the default data type for integral values unless there is a concern about memory.

The default value is 0.

Example: int a = 100000, int b = -200000

**long:**

Long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer.

Minimum value is -9,223,372,036,854,775,808.(-2^63)

Maximum value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). (2^63 -1)

This type is used when a wider range than int is needed.

Default value is 0L.

Example: long a = 100000L, int b = -200000L

Answer (score 0):

It is not about the declaration at all. I'm not going into a verbose answer. Just simply try this first

```
System.out.println(123L);
```

and then

```
System.out.println(123F);
```

That should clear things for you :)