# Arduino left shift not working as expected, compiler bug?

Tags: c++, arduino, integer, arduino-uno

```
uint32_t a = 0xFF << 8;
uint32_t b = 0xFF;
uint32_t c = b << 8;
```

I'm compiling for the Uno (1.0.x and 1.5) and it would seem obvious that `a` and `c` should be the same value, but they are not... at least not when running on the target. I compile the same code on the host and have no issues.

Right shift works fine, left shift only works when I'm shifting a variable versus a constant.

Can anyone confirm this?

I'm using Visual Micro with VS2013. Compiling with either 1.0.x or 1.5 Arduino results in the same failure.

## EDIT:

On the target:

```
A = 0xFFFFFF00
C = 0x0000FF00
```

Comment: What are their values?

Comment: What's the default integer size on the platform in question? `b` is promoted to a 32 bit value on assignment, so when you shift it left later there's no question of overflow. If the default integer size was 8 bits then the assignment to `a` would overflow.

Comment: I cannot confirm this.  On eclipse both a and c end up with a value of `0xFF00`.

Comment: What values are you actually getting? Is it possible that the first value is sign extended to 0xFFFFFF00?

Comment: @LouisNewstrom If Eclipse is using native gcc, then your results match mine for host.  It's the target that's having issues.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I think that's it.  If I give value of 0x000000FF which shouldn't be signed, it still is treating the constant as signed though.  Going to play around with it more.

Comment: So, `0xFF << 8` is `0xFF00`, which is still signed. Try using `0xFFU << 8U`. Or `0xFFL << 8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the signed/unsigned implicit cast.

With `uint32_t a = 0xFF << 8;` you mean

- `0xFF` is declared; it is a `signed char`;
- There is a << operation, so that variable is converted to int. Since it was a signed char (and so its value was -1) it is padded with 1, to preserve the sign. So the variable is `0xFFFFFFFF`;
- it is shifted, so `a = 0xFFFFFF00`.

> NOTE: this is slightly wrong, see below for the "more correct" version

If you want to reproduce the same behaviour, try this code:

```
uint32_t a = 0xFF << 8;
uint32_t b = (signed char)0xFF;
uint32_t c = b << 8;

Serial.println(a, HEX);
Serial.println(b, HEX);
Serial.println(c, HEX);
```

The result is

```
FFFFFF00
FFFFFFFF
FFFFFF00
```

Or, in the other way, if you write

```
uint32_t a = (unsigned)0xFF << 8;
```

you get that `a = 0x0000FF00`.

There are just two weird things with the compiler:

1. `uint32_t a = (unsigned char)0xFF << 8;` returns a = 0xFFFFFF00
2. `uint32_t a = 0x000000FF << 8;` returns a = 0xFFFFFF00 too.

Maybe it's a wrong cast in the compiler....

EDIT:

As phuclv pointed out, the above explanation is slightly wrong. The correct explanation is that, with `uint32_t a = 0xFF << 8;`, the compiler does this operations:

- `0xFF` is declared; it is an `int`;
- There is a << operation, and thus this becomes `0xFF00`; it was an int, so it is negative
- it is then promoted to `uint32_t`. Since it was negative, `1`s are prepended, resulting in a `0xFFFFFF00`

The difference with the above explanation is that if you write `uint32_t a = 0xFF << 7;` you get `0x7F80` rather than `0xFFFFFF80`.

This also explains the two "weird" things I wrote in the end of the previous answer.

For reference, in the [thread linked in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108642/type-of-integer-literals-not-int-by-default) there are some more explanations on how the compiler interpretes literals. Particularly in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8108715/3368201) there is a table with the types the compiler assigns to the literals. In this case (no suffix, hexadecimal value) the compiler assigns this type, according to what is the smallest type that fits the value:

1. `int`
2. `unsigned int`
3. `long int`
4. `unsigned long int`
5. `long long int`
6. `unsigned long long int`

This leads to some more considerations:

- `uint32_t a = 0x7FFF << 8;` this means that the literal is interpreted as a signed integer; the promotion to the bigger integer extends the sign, and so the result is `0xFFFFFF00`
- `uint32_t b = 0xFFFF << 8;` the literal in this case is interpreted as an unsigned integer. The result of the promotion to the 32-bit integer is therefore `0x0000FF00`

Comment: The weird things you pointed out 1 & 2 is what puzzles and was unexpected but at least it's workaroundable.  Thanks all.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the compiler. 0xFF is an `int`, **not `signed char`**. Integer literals must be [`int`, `long int` or `long long int`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8108642/995714). Because int is 16-bit wide in Arduino, 0xFF << 8 will be negative. Therefore the result would be `0xFFFFFF00` instead of 0xFFFFFFFF. Only after casting to `(signed char)0xFF` it'll become 0xFFFFFFFF. Even the "weird things" above is also correct. It's just that you don't know the C standard as well as the compiler

Comment: @phuclv I double checked this and... yes, that part of the answer was wrong; I fixed it to reflect this information.
Thank you for the time to fix a 4+ years old answer

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing here is that in Arduino **int is a 16-bit type**. That'll explain everything

1. For `uint32_t a = 0xFF << 8`: 0xFF is of type `int`<sup>1</sup>. `0xFF << 8` results in 0xFF00 which is a signed negative value in 16-bit int<sup>2</sup>. When assigning the `int` value to a `uint32_t` variable again it'll be sign-extended <sup>3</sup> when upcasting, thus the result becomes **0xFFFFFF00U**
2. For the following lines

   ```
   uint32_t b = 0xFF;
   uint32_t c = b << 8;
   ```

   0xFF is **positive** in 16-bit int, therefore `b` also contains 0xFF. Then shifting it left 8 bits results in 0x0000FF00, because `b << 8` is an `uint32_t` expression. It's wider than `int` so there's no promotion to `int` happening here

Similarly with `uint32_t a = (unsigned)0xFF << 8` the output is 0x0000FF00 because the positive 0xFF when converted to `unsigned int` is still positive. Upcasting `unsigned int` to `uint32_t` does a zero extension, but the sign bit is already zero so even if you do `int32_t b = 0xFF; uint32_t c = b << 8` the high bits are still zero. Same to the *"weird"* `uint32_t a = 0x000000FF << 8`. Instead of (unsigned)0xFF you can just use the exact equivalent version (but shorter) `0xFFU`

OTOH if you declare b as `uint8_t b = 0xFF` or `int8_t b = 0xFF` then things will be different, integer promotion occurs and the result will be similar to the first line (0xFFFFFF00U). And if you cast 0xFF to `signed char` like this

```
uint32_t b = (signed char)0xFF;
uint32_t c = b << 8;
```

then upon promoting to int it'll be sign-extended to 0xFFFF. Similarly casting it to `int32_t` or `uint32_t` will result in a sign-extension from `signed char` to the 32-bit wide  value 0xFFFFFFFF

If you cast to `unsigned char` like in `uint32_t a = (unsigned char)0xFF << 8;` instead then the `(unsigned char)0xFF` will be promoted to int using zero extension<sup>4</sup>, therefore the result will be exactly the same as `uint32_t a = 0xFF << 8;`

**In summary:** When in doubt, consult the standard. The compiler rarely lies to you

---

<sup>1</sup> [Type of integer literals not int by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8108642/995714)

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.

```
Suffix      Decimal Constant          Octal or Hexadecimal Constant
-------------------------------------------------------------------
none        int                       int
            long int                  unsigned int
            long long int             long int
                                      unsigned long int
                                      long long int
                                      unsigned long long int
```

<sup>2</sup> Strictly speaking shifting into sign bit like that is undefined behavior

- [1 << 31 produces the error, "The result of the '<<' expression is undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26319592/995714)
- [Defining (1 << 31) or using 0x80000000? Result is different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717899/995714)

<sup>3</sup> The rule is to add UINT_MAX + 1

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

- [Signed to unsigned conversion in C - is it always safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50605/995714)

<sup>4</sup>A cast will always preserve the input value if the value fits in the target type, so casting a signed type to a wider signed type will be done by a sign-extension, and casting an unsigned type to a wider type will be done by a zero-extension

Answer (score -1):

[Credit goes to Mats Petersson]

Using a cast operator to force the compiler to treat the 0xFF as a **uint32_t** addresses the issue. Seems like the Arduino xcompiler treats constants a little differently since I've never had cast before a shift.

Thanks!

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the compiler. The C standard specifies that 0xFF will be of type int (which is 16-bit wide in Arduino), and 0xFF << 8 is a negative number. Besides, any types smaller than int must be promoted to int