# 1 << 31 produces the error, "The result of the '<<' expression is undefined"

Tags: c++, c

If I have value declared as of type int on a 32 bit platform and perform the following:

```
int32_t mask;
mask = 1 << 31: // produces 2147483648 (or 0x80000000)
```

Can someone help me understand why the above line would produce the warning:

```
The result of the '<<' expression is undefined
```

Comment: Which compiler, which language, and which version of the standard? This is implementation-defined in C++14 and undefined in all other versions of C and C++.

Comment: @jww how is that a duplicate? The highest scoring answer explicitly states "shifts of 32 or more are undefined". This is about 31 times. The answer in this case is that the fact that a `int32_t` is a typedef for `signed long int` makes it an identical issue because it's signed.

Comment: Try the following to squash the warning: `mask = (int32_t)(1UL << 31);`

Comment: @Niels - read the question and answer. The shift causes a sign change in both this question and the cited duplicate. But you are right... The cited question should say "more than 31...".

Comment: see also [Why does (1 << 31) >> 31 result in -1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192284/why-does-1-31-31-result-in-1/)

Comment: note that the "duplicate" is a different question, however David Heffernan's answer answers both that and this

Comment: @jww yeah that was my sole point - it's not a full duplicate, but essentially the same issue for signed numbers.

Comment: we shoudl say that the shift will work if mask is uint32_t

Comment: @MattMcNabb Except that the answer is outdated due to the change in the standard.

Comment: Nominating to reopen as TC's answer is good and the linked duplicate is a different question with insufficient detail in the answer

Comment: @Matt - I'll be happy to follow your recommendation. This question needs to be disambiguated too (both [tag:c] and [tag:c++] tags). What should be done with the cited duplicate. Should it be cleaned up and then marked as a dup of this question? (I had the same feeling about some of the answers).

Comment: Either way, it's crap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

2<sup>31</sup> isn't representable in a `int32_t`, which goes from -2<sup>31</sup> to (2<sup>31</sup>-1). This is undefined behavior in C11 and C++11, and implementation-defined in C++14.

C11 §6.5.7/p4 (quoting N1570):

> The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions;
>   vacated bits are filled with zeros. [...] If `E1` has a signed type
>   and nonnegative value, and `E1 × 2`<sup>`E2`</sup> is representable in
>   the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.

The C++11 rule in N3337 §5.8 [expr.shift]/p2  is pretty much identical. Since 2<sup>31</sup> isn't representable, the behavior is undefined.

C++14  §5.8 [expr.shift]/p2 (quoting N3936; see also [CWG issue 1457](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1457)):

> The value of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions;
>   vacated bits are zero-filled. [...] Otherwise, if `E1` has a signed
>   type and non-negative value, and `E1×2`<sup>`E2`</sup>is representable
>   in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that
>   value, converted to the result type, is the resulting value;
>   otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

As 2<sup>31</sup> is representable in an unsigned 32-bit int, the behavior is defined and the result is 2<sup>31</sup> converted to `int32_t`; this conversion is implementation-defined per §4.7 [conv.integral]/p3. In a typical system using two's complement you'd get -2<sup>31</sup>.

Comment: And one reason this must be undefined / implementation defined is that ones' complement and twos' complement hardware will give different results for the expression 1 << 31 when evaluated as a signed 32 bit int.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement

Comment: Is all integer overflow implementation-defined in C++14, or just this case?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Just this case. The change is in fact designed especially to make `1 << 31` legal :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb true; the motivation for the change is to allow library writers to implement `numeric_limits::min()` and similar easily, and those people know what their implementation defines for this :)

Comment: `- max() - 1` was difficult I guess :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Also avoid breaking existing code due to `constexpr` additions (the optimizers may well be written to not consider `1 << 31` UB to avoid breakages, but it's UB by the standard and so requires a diagnostic in a `constexpr`)

Comment: Confident that that the "which usually goes from" is not just usually, bit always for `int32_t`.

Comment: `int32_t` is an exact width type.  C11 7.20.1.1 1 "The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation. ...".  So I still stand by that `int32_t` has a fixed range.  If a system cannot support "width N, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation", it does not support `int32_t`.

Comment: @chux Actually, even for 2's complement, the C standard allows sign-bit 1 and all-value-bit zero to be a trap representation (6.2.6.2/2). So I believe it's legal for to have a `int32_t` that has a two's complement representation but still have the range (-2^31 + 1) - (2^31 - 1), with what would usually be -2^31 being a trap representation instead.

Comment: @T.C. Sounds like we agree `INT32_MAX` must be `2^31 - 1`.  I see the strength of your point concerning `INT32_MIN`, but §7.20.2.1 1  appears quite explicit: "minimum values of exact-width signed integer types `INTN_MIN` exactly −(2N−1)".

Comment: @chux Interesting, so they implicitly ban `intN_t` from having a trap representation.