# Defining (1 << 31) or using 0x80000000? Result is different

Tags: c, casting

```
#define SCALE (1 << 31)

#define fix_Q31_80(x) ( (int) ( (float)(x)*(float)0x80000000 ) )
#define fix_Q31_SC(x) ( (int) ( (float)(x)*(float)SCALE      ) )

int main()
{
    int fix_80 = fix_Q31_80(0.5f);
    int fix_sc = fix_Q31_SC(0.5f);
}
```

Why are the values `fix_80` and `fix_sc` different?

```
fix_80 == Hex:0x40000000
fix_sc == Hex:0xc0000000
```

Comment: Who knows? UB is UB, [IB is IB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331035/why-was-1-31-changed-to-be-implementation-defined-in-c14). Don't do it if you want predictable results.

Comment: Because, even if the results are well defined on your implementation (which they may not be)   `(1 << 31) != 0x80000000`

Comment: just don't use signed integer types when bit shifting

Comment: @Danijel  This 0x80000000 is a positive integer constant that can have type long. At the same time 1 << 31 is an integer expression that yields a negative number.

Comment: `1 << 31` is UB for 32-bit `int`. Use `1U << 31` which has a the same type as `0x80000000` in a system with 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`1 << 31` is undefined behavior on most platforms (e. g., systems with 16-bit or 32-bit `int`) as its result cannot be represented in an `int` (the resulting type of the expression). Don't use that expression in code. On the other hand `1U << 31` is a valid expression on systems with 32-bit `int` as its result is representable in an `unsigned int` (the resulting type of the expression).

On a 32-bit `int` system, `0x80000000` is a (relatively) big positive integer number of type `unsigned int`. If you are lucky (or unlucky) enough to not have  demons to fly out of your nose by using `1 << 31` expression, the most likely result of this expression is `INT_MIN` which is a (relatively) big negative integer number of type `int`.

Answer (score 5):

All integer constants have a type. In the case of `1`, the type is `int`. On a system with 32 bit integers, `1 << 31` gives a number which is too large to be represented as an `int`. This is undefined behavior and therefore a bug.

But `0x80000000` will work as expected, because on a 32 bit system it happens to be the type `unsigned int`. This is because decimal constants and hexadecimal constants behave differently when the compiler goes looking for what type they should have, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34183176/584518).

As several people have mentioned, don't use bitwise operators on signed types.

Answer (score 1):

0x80000000 is a big number which needs 32 bit to represent that number. This means on a 32 bit system (or in a 32 bit compatible application) an `int` is too small. So use `unsigned long` instead:

```
#define SCALE (1u << 31)

#define fix_Q31_80(x) ( (unsigned long) ( (float)(x)*(float)0x80000000u ) )
#define fix_Q31_SC(x) ( (unsigned long) ( (float)(x)*(float)SCALE       ) )

int main()
{
    unsigned long fix_80 = fix_Q31_80(0.5f);
    unsigned long fix_sc = fix_Q31_SC(0.5f);
}
```