# C define, letter L after nuber

Tags: c, types

I am reading old c code(1991), and i don't understand something, there is a define like:

```
#define SLEEP_MIN      (SLEEP_SEC*60L)
```

`SLEEP_SEC` defined as `60`, what the `60L` means?

Comment: It stands for the `long` datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an integer literal.

In particular, the `L` stands for a literal of type `long`.
As an integer literal is of type `int` [by default (or not)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108642/type-of-integer-literals-not-int-by-default), the `L` suffix explicitly says that the literal is of type `long`, effectively making `SLEEP_MIN` a `long` (as far as a macro can have a type).

Answer (score 0):

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.4.4.1, Integer constants

> #### Syntax
>
> *integer-constant:*
>   decimal-constant integer-suffix <sup>opt</sup>
>
> *integer-suffix:*
>   unsigned-suffix long-suffix<sup>opt</sup>
>   unsigned-suffix long-long-suffix
>   long-suffix unsigned-suffix<sup>opt</sup>
>   long-long-suffix unsigned-suffix<sup>opt</sup>
>
> *long-suffix:* one of
>   `l`  `L`

So, `60L` is making `60` to a type of `long`.

Related: Why the `L` is required,

> [5] The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can
>   be represented.

So, withouth the `L` suffix, `60` will be treated as `int`.