# Where in the C++ standard can I read what type an integer literal is?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, literals

In chapter "lexical conventions/Literals" it simply mentions that without suffix, it could be any of int, long int or long long int. Where does it explicitly state it being implementation defined or - if not - what type it is?

Comment: Didn't you just answer your question?

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: I think your question is "how do I determine the type of an integer literal in a particular compiler implementation?" right?

Comment: In the section you refer to is says *"The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list in Table 7 in which its value can be
represented."*. So 123456 is an int if it fits, otherwise it is long or long long.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type of integer literals not int by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108642/type-of-integer-literals-not-int-by-default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `lex.icon`, the second paragraph, there is a table. Before the table it says

> The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list in Table 6 in which its value can be represented.

And then in the table, under decimal constants, it lists, in order, `int`, `long int`, `long long int`. So according to the above statement, if it can be represented by an `int`, then it's an `int`. If it can't be represented by an `int`, but it can be represented by a `long int`, then it's a `long int`. And if it can't be represented by a `long int` but it can be represented by a `long long int`, then it's a `long long int`.

There are different rules for octal and hexadecimal constants, which allow them to be unsigned types, ordered for priority as `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned long long int`.